# spring - method for all request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There is a way (in Spring) to define a method  that must be called for all request, similar to @modelAttribute???

I would like to define a method to carry out checks and put in session object for each request, the method is the same

In this method i will receive "Principal" (null, before authentication and with username...ecc after)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter.

Take a look at this article:

http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter

Just create a class that extends it and make it a component.   Then you can map the interceptor to a specific url patterm in your applicatioContext.xml.

```
 <mvc:interceptors>  
 <mvc:interceptor>  
     <mvc:mapping path="/*.svc"/>  
    <bean class="com.netsoft.skydive.controllers.SecuredApiEndpoint"></bean>  
 </mvc:interceptor>  
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer - simply use the `HandlerInterceptor` and inherit from e.g. `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`. The most convenient way to go is probably to use Spring's java configuration as in the following code example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="my.base.package")
public class MyWebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {
            @Override
            public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, final Object o) throws Exception {
                // Do stuff with your interceptor
                return true;

            }
        }).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

For more info on this, check out the excellent [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).